# Remove third-party Google Sheet Add-On and UI Menu

Tags: google-spreadsheets, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I installed [Numerous.ai](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/numerousai/575253125118) third-party Add-On for Google Sheets (CAREFUL - DO NOT INSTALL IT). I didn't like it, so I then deleted it from Add-Ons (Extensions --> Add-Ons --> Manage Add-Ons --> Remove Numerous.ai).

It seemed to install itself as a custom UI menu as well, even though it's uninstalled as an Add-On:

[image]

It's literally not currently installed as an Add-On:

[image]

It also keeps popping up the install menu, prompting me to install it:

[image]

If I cancel, it says there's an error and keeps re-prompting me to install it:

[image]

I've also gone into Apps Script to see if it added its own code, but there's nothing there. I don't get how it's still existing as a custom menu item in Sheets if it's uninstalled??

[image]

This is disrupting my workflow. **How can I uninstall this seemingly-malicious third party Add-On from Google Sheets?**

Comment: With due respect, the "diagnostic" (saying that this was caused by add-on) is wrong as the "add-on" is not shown as a menu rather than an option insided the Extensions menu as it's shown the add-on "GPT for Sheets and Docs" and it's not shown as and installed add-on.

Answer (score 1):

I checked chrome://apps/ and did not see it there. I then tried chrome://extensions/, and it installed itself as an extension as well (I don't recall permitting this).

[image]

I removed the extension and add-on and this resolved the problem.

Comment: Congratulations to find yourself that the "problem" was caused by web browser extension instead of an add-on. For the sake of completeness, do  you remember the steps that you followed when tested the add-on? It's probably that one of the steps required to install the Chrome extension.